# Share custom image with Google+

Tags: php, google-api, google-plus

I am using Twitter,google+ and Facebook sharing on my website page,From which Facebook and Twitter are working fine but in Google+ it is taking default image with share link.I want it to be my own image as i did it in Facebook.I have tried:

1. -from http://www.addthis.com/.
2. ```
       <!-- Place this tag after the last share tag. -->
       <script type="text/javascript">
         (function() {
           var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
           po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
           var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
         })();
       </script>
   ```

   -from https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/
3. All of the ways to set the schema for the image 
   -from   https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/
   But none of them seems to work fine.Is there another way to set it done.?

Answer (score 2):

## Methods for Populating the +Snippet

**Use Schema.org microdata (recommended way):**

```
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <h1 itemprop="name">Shiny Trinket</h1>
  <img itemprop="image" src="{image-url}" />
  <p itemprop="description">Shiny trinkets are shiny.</p>
</body>
```

**Use Open Graph properties:**

```
<meta property="og:title" content="..." />
<meta property="og:image" content="..." />
<meta property="og:description" content="..." />
```

**Title and meta "description" tags:**

If the page's `<head>` element contains `<title>` and `<meta name="description" ... />` tags, the +Snippet uses the title and the content attribute of the description meta tag for the snippet description. For the thumbnail image, the sharebox attempts to find a suitable image on the page.

```
<title>...</title>
<meta name="description" content="..." />
```

**Best guess from page content (not recommended):**
If none of the previous data is present, Google parses the page and attempts to find the best title, description, and image.

Extracted from  [documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/#plus-snippet).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take your user to another tab use below code.

```
<a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>" >Share on Google+</a>
```

If you want a pop up window use the below code.

```
<a href="#" onclick="popUp=window.open('https://plus.google.com/share?url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>', 'popupwindow', 'scrollbars=yes,width=800,height=400');popUp.focus();return false">Share on Gogole+</a>
```